# converting to devise - capybara::ElementNotFound:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I am in the process of converting my user authentication from scratch to the devise gem.  All is completed and appears to be working fine.  I changed my rspec tests over, but I have one recurring problem that I have searched to find a solution to.

**The Error**

```
2) AuthenticationPages authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a    protected page after signing in should render the desired protected page
     Failure/Error: fill_in :email,    with: user.email
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label     'email' found
     # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:53:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**The Test**

```
describe "for non-signed-in users" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
            visit edit_user_registration_path(user)

            fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do
            it "should render the desired protected page" do
                page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
            end
        end
    end
```

**The Devise Form (new_user_session - appears before being allowed to see edit user info)**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %> 
  <% end -%>

  <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The behavior actually works properly when testing in the browser, but the rspec test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara cannot find the input for email; as the form seems properly built, most likely Capybara is being redirected to another page before reaching the form.

Are you sure that the path to follow to the form is `edit_user_registration_path(user)` and not for instance `new_user_registration_path` or (even better if you are testing sign_in and not sign_up) `new_user_session_path`?

Comment: Well the test is for a user that is not currently logged in to try and visit their edit form.   It should not allow this, and instead have a sign in form (which is the form I attached - new_user_session).  After the user creates a new session they are then redirected to the edit form that they initially intended to go. The test should then verify that after signin in the view should display "Edit User". I can not get capybara to sign the user in, before seeing the edit form.

Comment: Sorry @SeanL, I understand the flow, you're right. Can you check at what page is arriving Capybara? Your `visit edit_user_registration_path(user)` step is passing, so it is arriving somewhere.

Comment: I am quite perplexed on where capybara is going.  I tried commenting-out from the fill_in(user info) to click button - and change the bottom part of the test to see if the page should have h1, text: 'Sign in'.  It failed saying it Sign in is not displayed. Net Net I have no idea where capybara is going.  I am going to give up and comment out the test for now unless you have any other suggestions.  Thank you

Comment: @SeanL You can use `page.should have_content("hello world")` to see on the diff response the content of the page. I guess that it is at the edit_user page indeed.

Comment: Hmm I see - when I commented out login information and I did page.should have_content('sign in'), the test ended up passing; I believe I have the correct devise form in my question that capybara is going to. (sign in (failing) >> edit page)  Not sure where its going wrong :/  O well, thank you though